# Which package strategy use to achieve high cohesion and low coupling

Tags: java, software-design

My question is about achieve high cohesion but I think the next example promote low cohesion and high coupling and I would someone to explain me if this is the case or not, I am talking about the package strategy that is very common on any project that I have worked

```
com.example.dao.reservation 
    ReservationDAO
    ReservationDAOImpl
com.example.dto.reservation
    ReservationDTO
com.example.entity.reservation
    ReservationEntity
```

This example usually come with some bad habits we have both interface and the implementation public, also we need to expose the fields to a get and set in order to manage the State (and this sometimes leads to manage the State in other classes by validate a getter for nullity for example), also we cannot put things related together.

I think it would be a better approach to promote high cohesion and low coupling if we doing with this package strategy:

```
com.example.reservation
  ReservationDAO
  ReservationDAOImpl
  ReservationDTO
  ReservationEntity
```

In the second approach we can have package access to properties, methods, constructors and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard way to organize your packages, it depends on the preference of your team.

Personally, the first organization appears to have too many packages, and the second seems easier to comprehend. It is easier to understand the project when organized by feature rather than abstract function (example 'reservation' as opposed to 'dao'). When I see a package with only one or two files in it, that is a clue that the packaging might be too tight. On the other hand, when a package contains more than (arbitrary number here) 20 files, then it might be a candidate to refactor into smaller packages.

One note about entity classes: If you use Hibernate reverse engineering to build entity classes from the DB it's a good idea to keep them in a separate dir which can be deleted if necessary (since these are auto-generated files). Often this dir can have many files, which is OK since it maps to an entire DB. In this case, organize this folder by abstract function (entity) rather than feature.

I know you are in Java, but after working with Angular a while I came to see how to apply Angular Style Guide recommendations:

> "Consider creating a folder for a component when it has multiple
>   accompanying files (.ts, .html, .css and .spec)."

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-06

The above "organize by component" recommendation is like your organize by feature example ('reservation').

> "Do create folders named for the feature area they represent."
>
> "Why? A developer can locate the code and identify what each file represents
>   at a glance. The structure is as flat as it can be and there are no
>   repetitive or redundant names.
>
> Why? The LIFT guidelines are all covered.
>
> Why? Helps reduce the app from becoming cluttered through organizing
>   the content and keeping them aligned with the LIFT guidelines.
>
> Why? When there are a lot of files, for example 10+, locating them is
>   easier with a consistent folder structure and more difficult in a flat
>   structure."

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-07

Comment: Yes I have seen this structure in angular, and I agree with you that at least for me it easier to understand  and it is easier to know if a clases correspond to a feature, but even if this is related to the team preferences I still think that the abstract strategy promote some bad habits and is a widely accepted way of program at least for the last 10 years(in some places is the de facto way of program), but besides the entity case that you explain to me, do you know another advantage to use abstract strategy over feature?

Answer (score 0):

There's no widely accepted "best practice" for organizing packages.  My current preference is to do it according to the single responsibility principle.

Following SRP, every component (package, class, module, whatever) you write should satisfy either an external requirement, or a requirement of one other component implementation.  Since each component has at most one "boss" component, the component->boss links form a tree.

This SRP tree is an extremely important part of any software design, but it doesn't show up in the standard diagrams.  There's no standard UML arrow that means "source of requirements", and there's nothing in the standard diagrams that can even show that you followed SRP in the design.

So I use the package structure to simultaneously document the SRP decisions made in the project, and to ensure that SRP is actually followed:

- Top level packages satisfy external requirements
- Child packages satisfy requirements of their parent package implementation

This also works out very well in code and makes it much easier to figure out what belongs in which package, since it's no longer just grouping vaguely related stuff.

To answer your specific question about your reservation hierarchy, I would ask you this: "Is there a reservation component"?  The normal answer, if you're following a clear/onion/hexagonal/etc. architecture is "no".

You probably have a data access layer, and the data access components should be part of that.

You probably have an API layer, and the data transfer components should be part of that.

So, I like your hierarchy with `dto.*` `dao.*`, etc., better, but I would really prefer your packages to contain components of the system, like `com.example.api.dto.ReservationDTO`, because there are no external requirements around your DTOs.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate with a simple example, I mean the reservation example it was Just ilustrative, but maybe can you post an actual example of how it is the process? thanks